MINI 3 PHP Framework Controller Routing Issue on Live Server
I have developed many apps using Mini 3 which all work without issues on my local machine. When I upload the files however to the internet, all my Ajax calls to controller functions return 404 error not found.
for example, I make a call to "home/login", this works fine on my local machine but returns 404 error on my live server.
What might be the issue please?
I tried modifying .htaccess as seen on the internet to this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

which has not been helpful
